# Implementing an interface for an iterator

Tags: c++, tdd

I'm writing a class which will iterate over a set of handles. Basically I'm working against a bunch of C functions which implement the following interface:

```
SomeHandle getFirst(ParentHandle);
SomeHandle getNext(SomeHandle);
```

Here is my iterator's interface and its partial implementation. I need an interface so that I can Mock this iterator for the purposes of TDD.

```
template<class HandleT>
class IHandleIterator
{
public: 
    virtual void operator++() = 0;
    virtual const HandleT& operator*() const = 0;
};

template<class HandleT>
class HandleIterator : public IHandleIterator<HandleT>
{
public:
    // used by something.end()
    HandleIterator() : _isLast(true)
    {
    }

    // updates _isLast when the end is reached        
    virtual void operator++()
    {
    }

    virtual const HandleT& operator*() const
    {
        return _currentHandle;
    }

protected:
    HandleT _currentHandle;
    bool _isLast;
};
```

What I want to do is add operator!= to the interface to test when I've reached the end of what I'm iterating over, as follows:

```
for(IHandleIterator i=something.begin(); i!=seomething.end(); i++)
{
    *i;
}
```

However I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone offer me suggestions?

If I can't find a solution involving operator!= then I'm wondering if this is a good approach:

```
class IHandleIterator
{
public: 
    virtual void operator++() = 0;
    virtual const HandleT& operator*() const = 0;
    virtual bool isLast const = 0;
};

for(IHandleIterator i=something.begin(); !i.isLast(); i++)
{
    *i;
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Neither of those look good to me due to the idea itself.  Inheritance, virtual dispatch, badly-padded memory-wasting structures, a mixture of iterator and cursor approaches. Why? A solution looking for its problem?

Comment: Can’t you mock by using a template instead of an interface? This approach doesn’t mix with the way iterators are normally used in C++, because iterators are almost exclusively passed by value. This doesn’t work with interfaces. I’d also question the decision to mock iterators. Mock the collection that is represented by the iterators instead.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Why are iterators passed by value? Do you mean that I should do something like this: HandleIterator<MockHandle> h;

Comment: @Baz Because it’s cheaper and there’s usually no sense in not passing them by value. All standard library algorithms for instance pass iterators by value.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: OK I'll look more into this. Am I right in saying that you think I should unit test by having a MockHandle class which I used to instantiate my HandleIterator template class with?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: I'd appreciate it if you would elaborate more on your comment as I'm still only learning. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am not sure why you would not provide an iterator and rather mock a container for this case. I think I prefer just providing iterators (without having to provide a container wrapper for the data). What are the advantages/disadvantages? (In my case, I am thinking in `std::iota` (unstandard SGI), or `std::Xstream_iterator` there is no *container*, but you can have *iterators*. -- Oh, I see now. The mocking is for testing. Yes, you want to test the iteration, then leave the iterator alone and mock the underlying data.